# Ansible find files only if contains particular string

Tags: find, git, ansible

I need a small help in writing an ansible playbook. I have written the below till now which is listing all files with config basically. but I need to filter out the files which are basically .git/config

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: "Serching old git URL"
    become: true
    become_user: root
    find:
      paths: builds
      file_type: file
      recurse: yes
      patterns:
        - config$
      use_regex: true
      contains: 'atlgit-01.us.manh.com'

    register: configfiles
  - debug:
      msg: "{{configfiles.files | map(attribute='path')| list }}"
```

Below is the 0utput

```
"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-to/.git/config",
"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-to/environments/configure/configureEnv.xml",
"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-from/.git/config",
"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-from/environments/configure/configureEnv.xml",
"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-from/ui/help/Content/Resources/images/config.gif",
"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-from/ui/help/Content/Resources/images/configure_button.gif",
"/builds/v2020/CI/source/dockerqa/.git/config",
"/builds/v2020/CI/source/docker_ci/.git/config",
"/builds/v2020/escrow/.git/config"
```

Thanks you for the help

Comment: Does "filter out" mean "exclude" or "include exlusively"?

Comment: That output doesn't make sense: files like `"/builds/v2020/app/db-upgradesetup-from/environments/configure/configureEnv.xml` don't match the `patterns` configuration in your `find` task.

Comment: @larsk yes I just modified the regex to ^config$ .Now it gives me all the files from .git folder. That fixed my issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excludes option to the find command that I think will do what you want.
excludes: '.*./.git.config'

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html

Comment: for some reason exclude giving me error. I just modified my regex to ^config$ which solved my problem for the time being. If I could include only .git folder from search result that will be better solution